# Implement list-like index access in Python

Tags: python, arrays, list, indexing

I'd like to be able to access some values of a python object using array-like syntax, ie:

```
obj = MyClass()
zeroth = obj[0]
first = obj[1]
```

Is this possible? If so, how do you implement this in the python class in question?

Answer (score 70, accepted):

You need to write or override [`__getitem__`](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getitem__), [`__setitem__`](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__setitem__), and [`__delitem__`](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__delitem__).

So for example:

```
class MetaContainer():
    def __delitem__(self, key):
        self.__delattr__(key)

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return self.__getattribute__(key)

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        self.__setattr__(key, value)
```

This is a very simple class that allows indexed access to its attributes.

Answer (score 6):

Use the `__getitem__` and `__setitem__` methods.

```
class MyClass:
    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return some_value_related_to_key

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        # set value (if needed)
```