# When subclassing DataFrame how to write a wrapper method for 'loc'

Tags: python, pandas, subclass

I'm trying to write a wrapper method for a subclass of `DataFrame`

```
class SubDataFrame(DataFrame):
   ...

a = SubDataFrame()
b = a.loc[row, column]
```

in the last line I want to process metadata separately in class `SubDataFrame` before or after processing the `loc` in the superclass.

I don't know how to implement this notation because if I just define

```
def loc(self, *args, **kwargs)
```

method in `SubDataFrame` the `loc[]` bracket notation doesn't work. (`AttributeError: instancemethod has no attribute getitem`).

I can find no docs on how to implement this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, the way Pandas implements indexing is anything but simple.

In general, in order to use indexed access on an object (e.g., `obj[something]`), it needs to have `__getitem__` and `__setitem__` methods (see [here](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getitem__) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6486387/python-implement-list-like-index-access)).

In the case of a `DataFrame`, the `loc` property is not a method, but an object to which indexing is delegated:

```
>>> frame = pd.DataFrame()
>>> type(frame.loc)
pandas.core.indexing._LocIndexer
```

You can see the class definition [here](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/blob/master/pandas/core/indexing.py#L1545).  In this case, `_LocIndexer` inherits (eventually) from [`_NDFrameIndexer`](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/blob/master/pandas/core/indexing.py#L37), which defines the required `__getitem__` and `__setitem__` methods for indexed access.

If you want to intercept access via `.loc[]` in your subclass, you'll probably have to define some sort of proxy class that implements the desired behaviour before passing off to the original implementation.  I suspect this will be difficult and error-prone, though.

Comment: It's worth saying that this could be considered an abuse of notation on the part of Pandas, and it leads to exactly the sort of confusion that the OP is having.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. That is very confusing indeed and I think far too complex to maintain longterm. I will write a simple 'loc' instance method.