# What method is called when using an indexed reference from an instance of a class?

Tags: python, class

I'm using Python 3.7 on Raspbian.  I'm new to Python, so please forbear...

In the [example program](https://circuitpython.readthedocs.io/projects/ht16k33/en/latest/examples.html#id2), a module is imported `from adafruit_ht16k33 import segments`

In [segments.py](https://circuitpython.readthedocs.io/projects/ht16k33/en/latest/_modules/adafruit_ht16k33/segments.html#Seg14x4) a class is defined:
`class Seg14x4(HT16K33):`

Below that, the class I am using is inherited: `class Seg7x4(Seg14x4):`

In the [example program](https://circuitpython.readthedocs.io/projects/ht16k33/en/latest/examples.html#id2) for these classes, the object `display` is instantiated from this class: `display = segments.Seg7x4(i2c)`

The class Seg14x4 has a method `print`, which is used in the example program like this: `display.print(42)`

I understand this object.method(parameter) type of syntax. 
I can find the definition of the print method in the Seg14x4 class:  `def print(self, value):`

However, the example program I'm using also shows the class being called using an indexed syntax like this: `display[3] = 'B'`

I am trying to understand what method is called when the `display[3] = 'B'` syntax is used. I don't see anything like a "default method" in the class definitions. (although that may not be the correct terminology for Python). I read docs.python.org/3.3/tutorial/classes.html and did not see any example of the bracketed, indexed syntax. 
How does the class treat an indexed parameter like `display[6]` in terms of determining which method to execute?

Answer (score 1):

```
display[x] = y
```

...is transformed into...

```
display.__setitem__(x, y)
```

Similarly,

```
display[x]
```

...is transformed into...

```
display.__getitem__(x)
```

You can find a list of these ‘special method’ names [here](http://diveinto.org/python3/special-method-names.html). By implementing these special methods in your class, you can make your custom objects behave more like native python objects which can be manipulated using operators and syntax like indexing.

Comment: I didn't know what to search for when I asked, but the moderator provided a link to a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6486387/implement-list-like-index-access-in-python